# Subset a dataframe using data from another dataframes

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny

I have a scatterplot, I want to be able to filter the data for that scatterplot.[image]

You see four plots in this Image. 1) Middle green curve, 2) Upper Black Curve, 3) Lower Black Curve, 4) Blue Scatterplot.

I have all these in the form of the data frame:

Blue scatterplot:

```
df <- mtcars
geom_point(df, aes(x,y), color = 'blue')
```

Green curve:

```
geom_smooth(formula=y~x, method='loess', color='green3', se=FALSE, size=0.5)
```

Upper Curve:

```
geom_smooth(formula=y+1~x, method='loess', color='gray20', se=FALSE, size=0.5)
```

Lower Curve

```
geom_smooth(formula=y-1~x, method='loess', color='gray20', se=FALSE, size=0.5)
```

I want to filter the blue data points by black curve lines, such that only blue data points remaining should be in between these two black lines and outliers should have to be get removed.

I tried using `which`, `filter`, `Subset` functions. But, it is not working, it is not rendering the output that I want.

In the end, I want the scatter data which lies between those two black lines.

Comment: Can you please add the dataframe and R code used to produce the plot? Otherwise, it is not clear how to provide a solution

Comment: I am new to this, can you please tell me, how to add dataframe in my question. I have all the 4 dataframes in CSV files. FYI: The data frame is quite big.

Comment: In that case, can you please define the 3 curves? Is there a specific equation for them?

Comment: No, there are no specific equations for them.

Comment: Then how were they generated?

Comment: The middle green plot is generated by a stat_smooth function on a scatterplot and the other two black plots are generated by just a small increment and decrement in y values of the stat_smooth plot.

Comment: As I said previously, please provide a way for people to reproduce the plot. Otherwise, people are left guessing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I got my answer. But, I will still try to modify and update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we don't have your particular dataset, here's an approach that is based around using the `mtcars` dataset.  First, let's draw a plot similar to what OP has shared:

```
df <- mtcars

ggplot(df, aes(disp, mpg)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_point(color='gray60') +
  geom_smooth(formula=y~x, method='loess', color='green3', se=FALSE, size=0.5) +
  geom_smooth(formula=y+1~x, method='loess', color='gray20', se=FALSE, size=0.5) +
  geom_smooth(formula=y-1~x, method='loess', color='gray20', se=FALSE, size=0.5)
```

[image]

As you can see, the upper and lower lines are created by adding +1 or -1 to the y value for the formula, respectively.

The approach we are taking here is to define for every x value in the dataset (for every value of `df$mpg`), the "upper" and "lower" lines predicted using the `loess()` method.  We can then use those values to compare to the actual value of `df$disp` for every given `df$mpg` to decide if it is "inside" or "outside" those limits.

First, the formulas for upper and lower lines, as well as prediction of the upper and lower values:

```
fla_upper <- loess(formula=mpg+1 ~ disp, mtcars)
fla_lower <- loess(formula=mpg-1 ~ disp, mtcars)

df$upper <- predict(fla_upper, newdata=df)
df$lower <- predict(fla_lower, newdata=df)
```

Now we can create a `df$region` column that describes where each point lies in the dataset:

```
df$region <- ifelse(df$mpg <= df$upper & df$mpg >= df$lower, 'inside','outside')
```

Finally, to create the plot, we can just use `df$region` for the color aesthetic.  I also define the colors of the aesthetic explicitly here because the default color scheme is not as clearly able to demonstrate the point:

```
ggplot(df, aes(disp, mpg)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_point(aes(color=region)) +
  geom_smooth(formula=y~x, method='loess', color='green3', se=FALSE, size=0.5) +
  geom_smooth(formula=y+1~x, method='loess', color='gray20', se=FALSE, size=0.5) +
  geom_smooth(formula=y-1~x, method='loess', color='gray20', se=FALSE, size=0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('inside'='red', 'outside'='gray80'))
```

[image]

To filter out those "outside" points completely, you can use `subset()` and apply that to the `geom_point()` data field:

```
ggplot(df, aes(disp, mpg)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_point(data=subset(df, region=='inside'), color='red') +
  geom_smooth(formula=y~x, method='loess', color='green3', se=FALSE, size=0.5) +
  geom_smooth(formula=y+1~x, method='loess', color='gray20', se=FALSE, size=0.5) +
  geom_smooth(formula=y-1~x, method='loess', color='gray20', se=FALSE, size=0.5)
```

[image]

Now, in applying to your own data, you can use a similar approach.  However you defined drawing your upper and lower lines, just apply that formula to the x value in your dataset to create "upper" and "lower" regions.  Then you compare the actual y value to the predicted upper and lower values.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, I will try your approach. It surely is very helpful.

Comment: Can I use the same approach for 'lm' instead of 'loess'?

Comment: No reason why you would not be able to do so.  Just change the method used with `geom_smooth` for the plot of that line and obviously use `lm()` instead of `loess()`.